# Google Analytics custom variable from php variable (dynamic number)

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

How can i put this php variable as a custom variable into this javascript code?

I have a dynamic number that is generated on my landingpage uniquely for each visitor.
This is available as php variable;

$clicknumber

I have already the following code working with GA (javascript);

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

My Question: How can i put this php variable as a custom variable into this javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);

  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'clicknumber', <?= $clicknumber ?>, 2]);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

More information: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#setup

Comment: Probably no need to echo the entire script tag. Just use `<?= $clicknumber ?>` where you want to print the number.

Comment: After embedding the above script into my page, i still see the traffic coming in, so the embedding was succesfull.

Question: What do i have to do on the side of GA to see this extra parameter (clicknumber) appear?

Comment: For example you can create a widget at a dashboard. E.g.: I use setCustomVar to track SSL requests vs non-SSL requests and I created a pie chart on my Analytics dashboard. Look for "Custom Variable 1" in list of available parameters.